# Keeping track of variable values in django for loop and avoid duplicates

Tags: django, filter, tags, django-templates

I have got a for loops which has many same values for different objects. I am trying to keep track of only the unique values.

```
`{% with cla.lodge_name|stringformat:"s" as hotel_stayed %}
 {% if hotel_stayed not in unique_hotel_list %}<!-- How to do this?? in django template -->
    {% for lodge in lodges %}
    {% if lodge.lodge_name == hotel_stayed %}
        <div>....</div>
       `
```

I am having problem in creating a list which can append values so that I can check if the new value is present already in the unique_hotel_list. I also tried making a dictionary with name as a key and value as count. If count is greater than 1 no need to proceed. Also looked into filter tags but could not be successful.

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to do this in the python view code.

However, if you really need to do this in the template then the only way I can think of to do this relatively simply is if you create the html for all the hotels and add a "hidden" tag to the ones that are in the unique_hotel_list. So your div can look like:

```
<div
{% for hotel in unique_hotel_list %}
   {% ifequal hotel hotel_stayed %}
     hidden
   {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
>
</div>
```

Comment: After some thinking, I basically did everything that I did in template in view. Hence there was no problem that I had faced in template. I made a unique_hotel_list which I passed to template. It did work as I had originally wanted! thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This feels like you are asking for Y while your problem really is X.

Meaning: why are there duplicates in your list, in the first place? Are they "valid" and you need them somewhere else? Or do you *really* need a list without duplicates but maybe a count or grouping (also called aggregation).

I suspect you are doing a query on Django's ORM that does a join that results in duplicate rows. If you provide the initial Django code that creates that list you might get the right answer to your original problem.

In any case, this is complex enough to be done in the Django view.
Instead (or in addition) to the original list, add the modified list to the template context. Or create the data structure that fits the needs of your markup best.

Comment: @Rishdinha, Two type of objects that I am looking have many-to-many relationship. Hence, there are same value (hotels)  for different course and vice-versa.

Comment: The for loops are meant to find other hotels that was used along with a given hotel. So I have to look all the courses that used a given hotel and all other hotels in that course. Since, a hotel can be used by many courses, there are duplicates. So far, in templates, I can find all hotels used along with a given hotel and if a hotel is used by more than 1 course, it will show that more times.Thanks for direction.